# Python - Need to delete everything before and after a variable in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am needing to read data out of a text file and locate certain fields contained within. I've gotten the txt file into a string but now I'm needing to locate certain fields. The file looks like:

City: New York

First Name: John

Last Name: Jones

Address: 123 Main St.

If I were wanting to pull the first name "John" out, what is the best way to do that in python? I know I can do a .find for "First Name: " but then how to I use that index to delete everything before and after "John" so I'm just left with a varialbe "John"

```
readData = open("data.txt", more='r')
rawData = readData.read()
readData.close()

x = rawData.index("First Name:")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"? Are you intending to modify the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using such a clean and regular format you can do this pretty easily by reading each line and splitting on `:`  using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```py
with open("some_file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value, = line.split(": ", maxsplit=1)
```

or you can use a dictionary comprehension for a cleaner data structure representation:

```py
with open("some_file.txt") as file:
    {key, value for key, value in [line.split(": ", maxsplit=1) for line in file]}
```

Note that you will probably also want to wrap these in a `try-catch` block to handle badly made or corrupted files where there is a missing key or missing value.

Comment: `dict(line.split(": ") for line in file)` also works and is much cleaner, imo

Comment: better to use `for line in file:`, no need to use `.readlines`, it just occupies the memory

Comment: @Matiiss good point, I always forget you can iterate over File-like objects

Comment: @ddejohn using `dict` does work, but following the zen of python "explicit is better than implicit" a dictionary comprehension seems more explicit about what is does and how than casting with `dict`

Comment: following the zen of python you shouldn't pack the comprehension that densely for readability and perhaps complexity, either how it would then probably be better to assign that list comprehension (or even use a generator) to a variable and then use that instead of nesting the list comprehension (also for simplicity I would agree with @ddejohn (except that it may take a little bit longer to understand what it does))

Comment: FWIW, this also assumes there's only one chunk of information in the text file. Would be better to use a `d = defaultdict(list)` and append items on collision.

Answer (score 0):

For storing this kind of data, i would really suggest using JSON; as it is very easy to use and versatile, here's an example:

data.json file:

```json
{
  "city": "New York",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Jones",
  "address": "123 Main St."
}
```

Python file:

```py
import json #Python supports JSON from the get-go!
json_data = json.load(open("data.json"))

city = json_data['city']
first_name = json_data['first_name']
last_name = json_data['last_name']
address = json_data['last_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
def main():
    with open("./data.txt", "r") as f:
        searched_key = "First Name"
        value = ""
        for line in f:
            if searched_key in line:
                value = line[len(searched_key) + 2:]

        print(value)
```

You should implement it as a function to be more handy. Just make searched_key a parameter and return value.

Also using jsons or dictionaries are easier and faster than txt.

Comment: this will `print` (usually functions use a `return`) only the last value with that key, also I would suggest using `.split` for clarity

Comment: @Matiiss: Using `print` here is fine (they wrote it as a `main` function), but your other points are valid.